# Как метод "end" отправляет ответ клиенту в модуле "http" языка/рантайма NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Типичное использование `http.Response` на примере отправки клиенту простого текста:

```
response.
    setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain").
    write("Hello, world!").
    end();
```

Согласно описанию метода `end`,

> Вызов `writable.end()` сигнализирует, что более никаких данных во Writable записано не будет.
>
> Оригинал:
> Calling the `writable.end()` method signals that no more data will be written
> to the `Writable`.

При этом о том, что этот метод отправит ответ клиенту, ничего не сказано.
Но поскольку приведённый выше пример работает, остаётся сделать вывод, что вызов метод `end` делает что-то ещё.

Возникает также подвопрос: `response` отправляет сам себя на сторону клиента, или для его отправки используется другие классы/функции?

Comment: данные отправляются клиенту по мере выполнения функций write() с буферизацией (потому что по умолчанию включен режим Transfer-Encoding: chunked и отправляется по чанку за раз). end() сообщает что данных не будет, значит последний чанк можно завершить и сбросить в поток, записать 0 с двумя переводами каретки для сигнализации завершения данных (для корректной работы keep-alive). после чего можно закрыть соединение с клиентом

Comment: @Mike, благодарю Вас за комментарий! Значит, сам `end` ответа не отправляет, а отправляет `write`?

Comment: end то же отправляет, но окончание ответа, которое еще не было отправлено ранее